# Когда нужно использовать ООП?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Интересно было бы услышать мнения о том, когда нужно использовать ООП в delphi, какие-то примеры. Поделитесь своими соображениями и опытом!

Comment: начиная с сегодняшнего вечера! :-)

Comment: Разумно ...

Comment: В delphi -- почти всегда. Карма такая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я советую использовать ООП, когда программа работает с моделями реальных объектов.

Например, Приемная Комиссия в ВУЗе. Тут можно выделить такие реальные объекты, как абитуриенты и специальности, например. То есть создать 2 класса - абитуриент и специальность.

Ну, это может и не самый подходящий пример, но мне кажется, так проще всего, и понятнее на мой взгляд...

Comment: Да уж... 

Проблема с ООП в том, что почти во всех **простых** задачах оно притянуто за уши. Вещь для них искусственная и только усложняющая все дело.

Я не имею в виду *использование* готовых библиотек классов. К ООП это имеет весьма опосредованное отношение.

Answer (score 8):

Старайтесь почитать документацию по платформе/языку, прежде чем задавать вопросы. Используйте процедурное программирование там, где это уместно, и ООП там, где этого требует сам язык, соглашения о коде и прочее. Если язык позволяет писать код и тем, и другим способом, исходите из опыта других людей или из своего собственного.
ООП - это не панацея, если интересно, то почитайте что-нибудь вроде [Почему объектно-ориентированное программирование провалилось?](http://blogerator.ru/page/oop_why-objects-have-failed)
В любом случае, возможности языка лучше использовать максимально, это поможет в освоении других платформ и языков.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Но инструменты/курсы/книги для ООПеров -- нехилый бизнес, и пока не кончатся халявные деньги, окучивание буратинов будет успешно продолжаться.

Answer (score 5):

Дык, приехали...

Весь VCL в делфях - сплошное ООП. Каждая форма, фрейм, компонент - объекты.

Тоесть, ответ - практически всегда. Кроме консольных приложений, там иногда можно обойтись и без ООП.

Comment: Почти всегда: 

     Кроме консольных приложений, там иногда можно обойтись и без ООП

Консоль используют в основном новички для написания простецкого кода...

Comment: тут

    dir c:\windows\system32\*.exe

90% консольных прог. новички все это писали :-)

Comment: Ага и весь линукс заодно.

Comment: А еще модели глобального климата. Тоже простецие програмки. И тоже писаны новичками.

Comment: Что за [глобальное потепление вы тут развели](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82)? Тип приложения и использование (или неиспользование) в нём ООП - два не связанных между собой факта. KiTE пытался показать, что *катая и прилепляя* формочки мышкой дельфист, сам того не желая, в какой-то мере практикует ООП.

Comment: @karmadro4, мы обсуждаем постулат от @Asen  "Консоль используют в основном новички для написания простецкого код". К ответу @KiTE совершенно никаких претензий.