# Зачем нужны классы в python?

Tags: python, классы

И можно ли обойтись без них? То есть вообще в коде их не вводить и даже если код в 1000 строк.

Comment: Можно. Зачем нужны или не нужны написано в любом учебнике или главе по ООП.

Comment: Классы нужны для больших проектов, или если хочешь создать какой-то объект, который будет связан с другими файлами в проекте. А если пишешь в одном файле, то можешь и без объектов обойтись. И даже без функций)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Когда использовать классы (ООП)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042362/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f)

Comment: Затем же, зачем и в любом другом языке, и целом за тем же, зачем нужна и любая другая структуризация кода.