# Философия ООП или в каком случае создавать новые классы?

Tags: ооп, проектирование

Как понять, что под определённое состояние объекта необходим новый класс?

Приведу пример:
Есть телевизор, у него может быть 2 состояния - вкл./выкл. Как будто всё нормально, и это просто состояния, всё в одном классе. Но вот, по сценарию, этот телевизор должны сломать(разбить в щепки) и он уже будет выглядеть иначе. Отсюда неопределённость: в реальной жизни это тот же телевизор и как будто должен быть тот же объект, но в программе удобнее унаследовать сломанный телевизор от телевизора и переопределить его "внешний вид".

Итак вопрос, как понимать, когда создавать новый класс, а когда это просто состояние объекта?

Важное отличие от [предполагаемого дубликата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042362/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F) в том, что этот вопрос подразумевает, что уже какая-то модель, которую необходимо развивать, а не о создании модели. Вопрос в том, как понять грань между созданием нового класса в иерархии и свойством в старом классе.Если бы [предполагаемый дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042362/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F) был бы книгой, то данный вопрос можно было бы включить как главу.Но в рамках текущего ресурса, данный вопрос есть более узкий и конкретный "луч" [предполагаемого дубликата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042362/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F).

Comment: *"в программе удобнее унаследовать сломанный телевизор от телевизора и переопределить его "внешний вид""* --- почему так? Почему это не условное состояние "isBroken" ?  А то, как выглядит в UI - этим вообще класс не должен заниматься, а должен рендерить другой класс на основе свойства. Разве нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский   класс хранит текстуру отображаемую.

Comment: *"как понимать, когда создавать новый класс, а когда это просто состояние объекта?"* --- я бы сказал, что это дискуссионный вопрос. Потому что ситуации разные бывают и нужно выстраивать логику на основе текущего состояния ТЗ. А оно даже может поменяться. Но всё интереснее. В одном проекте, когда кто-то сделал наследование и это будет хорошим решением, в другом проекте - только всё нарушит и это будет плохим решением....

Comment: *" класс хранит текстуру отображаемую"*  --- Зачем он хранит текстуру? Опять же... выводом UI должен заниматься  не класс с логикой.... иначе это как-то отсутствует разделение обязанностей

Comment: @АлексейШиманский само собой, отображает вьюшка это всё, я знаю про mvc, но я пренебрёг хранением текстур  и храню их в классе потому, что это игра и я вряд ли в ней когда-нибудь буду менять интерфейс

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Когда использовать классы (ООП)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042362/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%9e%d0%9e%d0%9f)

Comment: Ну тут нужно смотреть по свойствам/функционалу. Если сломанный телевизор всё-равно должен поддерживать большинство свойств и функций исходного телевизора, то можно оставить старый объект, просто переключить ему какие-то свойства. Но в общем случае лучше создавать объект нового класса "сломанный телевизор", передав ему для инициализации свойств ваш старый объект. Скорее всего "сломанный телевизор" будет иметь другие свойства, чем полноценный телевизор, и совсем другие методы, поэтому лучше пусть это будет другой класс. А если нужны какие-то общие методы и свойства,то можно сделать общего предка

Comment: @CrazyElf оформите как ответ?)

Comment: @SpaceResearcher а какой ответ? разве ответ про сломанный телевихо это ответ на вопрос "как понимать, когда создавать новый класс, а когда это просто состояние объекта?"  или "в каком случае создавать новые классы?"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне кажется хорошим решением делать в таких случаях общего предка и оба класса наследовать от него, это что касается конкретности. Что касается общего случая - там это тоже рассмотрено, если автор оформит ответ ссылаясь на что-то и распишет пояснение как он пришёл к такому, то самом собой, это будет хороший ответ.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Если бы это тянуло на ответ, я бы сразу оформил как ответ )  Хотя посмотрим. Нужно развить мысль, может позже.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher *"мне кажется"* --- видите, как я и сказал - вопорс дискусионный. И как я писал выше - "зависит от". Что как раз в своём комментарии и продемонстрировал CrazyElf ..... Так что тут нет  идиного правильного ответа.. А вы, получается, просто шли за тем, чтобы хоть кто-то согласился ими словами и вы приобрели уверенность в том, чтобы сделать именно так)) Но к правильности это отнести сложно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дизайн кода - это скорее искусство, чем наука, а искусство неформализуемо. Так что никакой формулы тут нет, есть только *паттерны проектирования* (*design patterns*), которые можно реализовывать самыми разными способами (в зависимости от избранного языка, ТЗ, вашего воображения, накопленого опыта, привычек), а можно вообще обходиться без них, особенно в `C++`, где б*о*льший вес имеют *идиомы*.

Comment: Слишком общие рассуждения для ответа ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, какой вопрос - такой и ответ.